# C++ - Remove last part of url

Tags: c++, qt

Is there any way to remove part of URL ?

I have a path of file with specific extension , and I want remove file name and extension.

Here is my code:

```
QString path;
if (path.right(3) == "jpg")
 QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(path));
else 
  ?
```

for example :

I want

C:\Users\me\Desktop\

instead of

*C:\Users\me\Desktop\file.exe*

Comment: The [`QFileInfo`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfileinfo.html) class will do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`QFileInfo`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html#absolutePath) class and the `absolutePath` method:

```
QString filePath = QFileInfo(path).absolutePath();
```

Answer (score 0):

Search backwards through the string for the first occurrence of '/' or '\' and stop.